# mod_rewrite already enabled but still get 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm building a URL friendly system. Host is a local machine, Ubuntu 15.10.

The software was working, but i made a mistake and removed an apache2 directory. So i purged apache with `sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 mysql-server`, then i reinstalled all: `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server`.

After reinstalled i tested a common site and the server was on. Then, finally, i enabled mod_rewrite again: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. And restarted apache2: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. So, everything seems on the place, but when i try my friendly url system, that was working before, i just get a 404 error.

Can someone help me?

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Note that this .htaccess is the same that was working before and i did not changed anything on the source codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your `VirtualHost`s (and then `httpd.conf`) configuration files for the [`AllowOverride`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#allowoverride) directive.

Set it to allow all declaration inside an `.htaccess` file:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I did not know about this other configuration. Now i know. Thank!